# Looking for a Function that insert "Any" form values to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am Looking for a Function that insert "Any" form values to mysql , update or delete with php. (or can we do this with one function?)
(not OOP)
I have found a function [here](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

example: get all fields of form and ınsert into database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is very unclear. Also, format the link as a link, not as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it entirely automated. Field names must be hard-coded in your script. The rest is pretty easy.
May be this one would help you.

```
/* the only 2 variables you have to edit for the particular table: */
$table="contacts";
fields=explode(",","name,surname,lastname,street,city,region,zip,country");

$query="INSERT INTO $table SET ".dbSet($fields);
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);

function dbSet($fields='') {
  $q='';
  foreach ($fields as $v) $q.=$v."='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$v])."', ";
  return trim($q,", ");
}
```

The `$fields` array contain field names which must be the same in the form and the database. E.g. you have a table with a `name` field. So, the form `<input>` must have the same name.` Consequently, field contents will go to the right column in the database.

If you're looking for a tool to edit an unknown database, PHPMyAdmin may help you. You can try it here http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/ (login `root`, empty password).